# Latex & Markdown files

Tags: luatex, markdown

I am writing my project docs in latex but I have a bunch of markdown (.md) files to include as chapters. I have a problem when latex parses the md files it reads all the tables and figures as plane text but does not render the tables nor the images. 
My environment is Mac OSX Mojave using MacTex-20180417, my editor is TexMaker with the LuaLatex engine.
My file looks like:

```
\usepackage[blankBeforeHeading, html, fencedCode, 
            inlineFootnotes, citations, definitionLists, 
            hashEnumerators, smartEllipses, hybrid]{markdown}

\begin{document}

\markdownInput{myfile.md}

\end{document}
```

myfile.md includes a basic table and a figure but the pdf output only displays the raw data. eg:  |this|is|my|table|.

My question is: Is there anything else I have to setup or any package to inlude in order to render the table and the figure?

i add a minimal example I made [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1J5PCjC-ZAyQ1XwpLWxO2NmqlZMP-aG18)

Comment: Please add a compilable MWE. Also, welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I added the MWE in the post

Comment: Please don't add links to MWEs. Instead edit your question to show the code directly.

Comment: The last time I checked the package did not support table rendering. Did you check the documentation?

Comment: I checked the documentation but there is no such section so I will try to search another way to solve this issue

Comment: According to the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/markdown/markdown.html), setting the option `pipeTables` should do the trick

Comment: I have tried to set this option before but it throws me the following error "Package xkeyval: `pipeTables´undefined in families `markdownOptions´ "

Comment: By the way: Your MWE is not compilable. Please have a look here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the option `pipeTables`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[blankBeforeHeading, html, fencedCode,
            inlineFootnotes, citations, definitionLists,
            hashEnumerators, smartEllipses, hybrid, pipeTables]{markdown}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.md}
This file is generated as a test for tables:

| Version | Date        |Paragraph| Description       | Author|
|:--------|:------------|---------|:------------------|-------|
| 1.0     | 12/Abril/19 | All     | initial commit    | RACG  |
| 1.0     | 12/Abril/19 | All     | initial commit    | RACG  |

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \markdownInput{\jobname.md}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe You should take a look at Pandoc: https://pandoc.org/ and convert .md files to LaTeX files?

Comment: I have used pandoc before but at the time I only want to render the tables and images everything else in my document is working fine